# Unable to deploy using firebase 3.0.0

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase

I'm trying to deploy using firebase 3.0.0 latest CLI version.
Unfortunately I get this errors:

```
Error: Unable to authorize access to project XXXX

Note: This version of the Firebase CLI is only compatible with projects upgraded
to the new Firebase Console. To access firebase.com apps, you will need to
use a previous version: npm install -g firebase-tools@^2.1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe you need to upgrade your project to the new Firebase at [firebase.google.com](http://firebase.google.com).  If you haven't you should check out the announcements at Google I/O 2016.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact I was trying to deploy to a custom domain that was not yet verified.
My bad :(
Sorry guys.